# In AWS, writing larger content to a file PutFile rest API is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, large-file-upload

In AWS, what is the file size limit adding from command line ?
I am trying to fetch the schema ddl using dbms_metadata.fetch and trying to add to a file into AWS using PutFile Rest API of AWS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_PutFile.html

For larger schema > 60KB , everything working good without any error , but when I look back at AWS console I am not seeing the file which I have created. Means file is actually not getting created.
any idea how can I overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

The limits are described on the [Quota page for AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/limits.html). For individual files this is 6 MB, so you should have received an error message if you were trying to upload a file larger than this. Below is from the CLI, but will be similar when using the API directly.

```
An error occurred (FileContentSizeLimitExceededException) when calling the PutFile operation: The maximum file size for adding a file from the AWS CodeCommit console or using the PutFile API is 6 MB. For files larger than 6 MB but smaller than 2 GB, use a Git client.
```

Or, via the Console:

[image]

If you're saying though that the operation was successful, but you're not seeing the file in CodeCommit, the problem is probably not related to the file size.

Please check if you've followed the right Git procedures for committing and pushing the file. And make sure that you're viewing the same branch as the one that you've pushed the file to.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the reply.
I did verify in the correct branch where I am trying to push the file.
Also if any issue with my GIT procedure which I am using , it shouldn't work for smaller content as well right ? but it is working 
I am able to see the file with smaller content getting pushed with same API which I have used for larger content.

Comment: Correct - if it works for smaller files, your Git procedure is likely not the problem. You were saying that you've tried uploading the file via API - can you verify what happens if you upload the file via CLI or the Console? When doing it via the Console, you should either immediately see the file after page refresh, or see an error message.